# Passing an Image with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ajaxform

HTML form for uploading an Image:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<input type="file" id="image">
<button type="button" class="ImgSubmitButton" onclick="uploadImages();">UPLOAD IMAGE</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript/Ajax for sending the data.

```
var RequestObject = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    RequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    RequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function uploadImages() {
    if (RequestObject) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var myfile = document.getElementById('image').files[0];
        formData.append('file', myfile);
        RequestObject.open("POST", "processFileA.php");

        RequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        RequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (RequestObject.readyState == 4 && RequestObject.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('err').innerHTML = RequestObject.responseText;
            }
        }
        RequestObject.send("data=" + formData);
    }
    return false;
}
```

PHP is simple just to check if the data is set.

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){ 
echo $_POST['data'];
echo "data is set";
} else {
echo "data is not set";
}
```

I've checked 3 header requests.

First:the data isn't set.

```
RequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
```

Second:the data isn't set.

```
RequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" + Math.random().toString().substr(2));
```

Third:returns this [object FormData].

```
RequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

I have also tried no header requests and data isn't set.

I know how to safely process the form through regular form submit with PHP, but not sure how to handle [object FormData] as it is passed via Ajax.  If their is a better method or something I'm doing wrong please let me know. My question is how do I properly send the image file Via Ajax to process it as you would in a regular form submit to properly process it in PHP.

Please no JQuery.

Comment: try use print_r($_FILES) and see if you file image received

Comment: I get Array ( ) 1 with print_r($_FILES) using this RequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');   Still isnt set with the other 2 header requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem in this string:

```
RequestObject.send("data=" + formData);
```

when you try String + `formData`, you did concatenation, and formData convert to String to, as we know `formData` it's object.

this is correct approach to send data:

```
RequestObject.send(formData);
```

just send a data like in this examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript

Comment: I get this    Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 2500. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0   and it returned data is not set.

Comment: can you try with small image

Comment: try in php var_dump($_POST) and see what inside

Comment: yes i just did no warning but it returned data is not set

Comment: data not set with var_dump($_POST) and var_dump($_FILES)

Comment: hmm you must see something like this "array(0) {
}"

Comment: if i use RequestObject.send("data=" + formData); is see array(0){}, but if i use RequestObject.send(formData); data is not set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185999/discussion-between-vadim-hulevich-and-jonny).

Comment: I also had to use   if(isset($_FILES))   instead of   if(isset($_POST)) on the PHP Side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use diffrent way by ajax see example bellow :

> THIS ANSWER WITH JUST JAVASCRIPT AJAX

```
<html>
<head>

<script >
function uploadImages(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "processFileA.php";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
//xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var content= xhr.responseText;

    console.log(content);



    }
};

var datae=document.getElementById('uploadimage');
var data = new FormData(datae);
xhr.send(data);
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="uploadimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<input type="file" name="file" id="image">
<button type="button" class="ImgSubmitButton" onclick="uploadImages();">UPLOAD IMAGE</button>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

> THIS ANSWER USING JQUERY AJAX

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed|Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: "processFileA.php", // Url to which the request is send
type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
{
alert('done')

}
});
}));



});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="uploadimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<input type="file" name="file" id="image">
<button type="submit" class="ImgSubmitButton" >UPLOAD 
            IMAGE</button>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP FILE : processFileA.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES["file"]["type"]))
{
$file=(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name']));
file_put_contents('tmp_name.'.str_replace('image/','',$_FILES["file"]["type"]),$file);
}
?>
```

Comment: cant use jquery

Comment: @Jonny ah you using just javascript ok i updated my code check it

Comment: I get data not set with this solution.